# I want more fireflies

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

Haha, that's something different for once. Any good suggestions how to achieve an esthetic grain on renders in Cycles; to give it a retro and analogue vibe.

Comment: If you read about [film grain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Film_grain) and fireflies, you'll see that *fireflies* are more like a digital artefact and film grain is a physical texture.

Comment: If you really want fireflies just shoot your lights through a Glass BSDF.